# Changes in data are not reflected to DropDownList in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We have DropdownLists in our Asp.Net Mvc views. We fill them with data through jquery ajax posts.

In Internet Explorer, changes in data would not be seen in DropdownList UNTIL we press Ctrl + F5.

Since we could not go to production with it, we needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that Internet Explorer is caching ajax posts by default.

Solution is to add `cache: false` to your post, like below:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "ourUrl",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        //stuff
    }
});
```